# Date Format Shows Only Month in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

when I try to use visual studio from my home PC, when I look at how it will display the date format, it only gives the number of the current month. So, although it should say 18.02.2024, it just says Month = 2. There is no such problem on the company's PC. I searched the net, but I couldn't find an answer. Can you help me on this issue? I leave the picture below, I hope I was able to explain what I mean.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFUmV.jpg)

This is the first time I encountered such a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I researched on the internet and asked on visual studio forums, but I couldn't get an answer.